# Using texture data from texture properties as node data in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor, properties

either I'm clearly missing something or I misunderstood the concept, but I hit a wall with something that should be pretty easy (provided it is already implemented in Blender).

I'm basically creating a 'stencil' (for lack of my imagination or better word for it) for character creation in which all the fine skin details such as pores and scars are procedurally generated with displace modifiers.

[image]

Almost all of these modifiers are fed with distorted noise procedural textures from texture properties - it is done like that for a quick change of attributes and randomisation on each character.

[image]

So far it's working like a charm as it creates great results when combined with vertex group masking. BUT! What I want/need is to use this texture data as a mask in Cycles nodes in terms of color differentiation for these moles, scars etc. We already have Basic noise textures in Cycles working just like that and we have all the texture information needed in Texture properties, yet I can't find a way to connect it to Cycles.

I know I can use it as a brush stencil, paint it onto a plane and save it as an image, but A) it loses the randomisation possibility and B) it only works when the displace Texture coordinates is set to UV. So this is not the way to do it. I'm either thinking of somehow projecting the texture color on a character and baking it (but I can't feed it to shader), creating a complex shader node that does and contains everything that Texture properties do (which requires a peek in the correct code) or using some kind of a script (but I don't know where to even begin).

The easiest way would sure be just to find a way to access this texture data in Cycles nodes, but I'm starting to believe it simply can't be done right now. I'm using and have tried to find solution in Blender 2.80.75 and Blender 2.79b. Any help or insight would be appreciated.

Cheers, Martin